# How can create a ceiling in a wet area?

Tags: ceiling

I have a wet area that has joists across it and need to create a ceiling for it. I do not want to use drywall because the area experiences significant humidity, so mold would develop in drywall. The ceiling needs to be waterproof and breathable so it can easily dry out.

So, it would seem I need some kind of panel system, but I have never seen anything like this, so I am unsure how to fabricate the ceiling.

Comment: Can you better define "wet"?   Is this a pergola exposed to rain?  A shower stall in a bathroom?  An outdoor or indoor swimming pool?  What is above it?   Is the ceiling or roof subject to flooding?  Or just condensation and humidity?  Without more context, I could suggest a glass ceiling like an indoor water amusement park, or a tarp or concrete or anything at all.

Comment: @jay613 It is an area below a house adjacent to the basement. One side of the area is open to the elements.

Comment: So it's an outdoor area with an overhang from the floor above?  What is the construction of the floor above and how is it currently finished on its bottom side?

Comment: @jay613 The part of the house above the area has a hardwood flooring installed on top of mahogany decking which is on top of the joists.

Comment: I would think then, insulation between the joists and a ceiling depending on the appearance you want.  Could be stained or painted wood planks, or treated plywood covered with paint or siding, or pretty much any material suitable for exterior or suitable when painted.

Comment: I'm really baffled now. You've got a room that overhangs free space below. The floor of this room has joists exposed to the elements below that were covered in mahogany decking which was then hidden by a hardwood floor? Why wasn't this properly covered & insulated when it was built? Why would you cover a nice mahogany floor with "hardwood flooring", isn't mahogany a hardwood? So much missing information from a user who's been around for quite some time.

Comment: @FreeMan What does it matter how the room above is constructed? The question is about the ceiling of the subgrade room.

Answer (score 2):

If the humidity is *that* high (steam room? steam shower stall in a bathroom?), then use the same materials and waterproofing techniques on the ceiling that you'll be using on the walls, namely cement board and a waterproofing membrane.

Whatever it is you're using for the walls, just continue it up and over onto the ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Simple to use metal roofing or fiberglass roofing on the underside of the decking sloped to the outside.  If light comes through the decking use clearer panels. Fiberglass panels are easier to use. Before installing run purlins of different thickness, less at back near the house and progressively thicker towards the end where you want the water to go. At that point install a gutter to direct the water where you choose.  Check this out for better understanding:https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/under-deck-roof/

Answer (score 0):

No idea what area (sq.m.) is to be covered, but sheets or panels of fibreglass, plastic or pvc are available. Frame round the edge, (and in between, if large) and they interlock - you could even put insulation above them, depending on span and edging. Google 'ceiling panels for wet room'.

Comment: I wouldn’t put fiberglass batt insulation in a high-humidity environment. Use rock wool insulation batts instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a faux pergola with a painted sky, fiber optic "stars", and so on.  Use treated plywood for the base and composite materials for the trim, if water resistance is required for those areas.

Comment: While this would be a treatment for the underside, it doesn't address waterproofing it. I'm not sure why it needs to be waterproofed, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Added notes re suitable materials.